Is there a way to get more control spells in Exalted 3E?
Now that Alchemicals is out in draft form, we are experimenting with some of its content, including some of the spells. With its spells added, my Twilight would very much like a second Celestial Circle control spell. But I'm not aware of a way to get more control spells other than initiating into the next higher circle of sorcery, and even that will only give me one more control spell and not until I hit E5.
I thought I saw a hearthstone that would do it previously, but I can't find the reference in the book now. Also, while a hearthstone would work work, it would not be my favorite answer since at the moment I don't have any open hearthstone sockets.
So, is there a canon way for my Twilight to get another control spell?
If there is no canon way, is there a balanced homebrew method? Exalted blatantly encourages a certain amount of homebrew. My storyteller is reasonably open to that kind of thing as long as it is balanced (at least as much as Exalted is ever balanced).
My thought is to learn the spell a second time. That seems to fit the in-universe explanation of a control spell being one that you have a deep understanding of and connection with, and I think that paying the XP cost and the training time a second time seems if anything overpriced for a control spell benefit in most cases. But I want to make sure I'm not overlooking anything that would make this unbalancing.

The Hearthstone you are thinking of is the Key of Mastery (Arms of the Chosen p. 135) and as far as I know it is the only effect like it that has been officially published.
I have almost no experience with 3e homebrew but the Hearthstone allows you to swap out which spell is your secondary control spell by reattuning to the stone, however paying for the spell twice is permanent...
You could make a custom charm with a similar effect to the Key of Mastery's evocation, but seems a strict upgrade and makes the stone less unique...
Ultimately it's up to your GM, wish I could help more.

Thanks. I wasn't looking in the right place to find it. Needing to get a greater, dependent hearthstone, something to socket it in, and then needing to pay the experience to awaken an evocation seems like a very high price for a control spell. But flexibility to change it occasionally is nice. And maybe I'm undervaluing the power of control spells? Or perhaps many of the hearthstones are meant to not be overly powerful?

I haven't been able to play much 3e unfortunately but it definitely seems like some Hearthstones and Control Spell bonuses are much more interesting/worthwhile than others.
